# How does this trick work in solving the 2-body central force equation of orbit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

I am working on understanding the derivation of Kepler orbits via section 8.5 of John R. Taylor's classical mechanics textbook, and one small detail has been tripping me up.

The equation being solved is
$$
\mu \ddot{r} = F(r) + \frac{l^2}{\mu r^3},
$$
where $\mu$ is the reduced mass of the two bodies, $r$ is the separation between them, $F$ is the central force, and $l$ is the angular momentum. (So that last term is a centrifugal force term).

Taylor makes the substitution $u \equiv 1/r$, and also shows that
$$
\frac{d}{dt} = \frac{l u^2}{\mu} \frac{d}{d\phi},
$$
which all makes sense to me. My problem is with the next line where he asserts that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(r) = \frac{l u^2}{\mu} \frac{d}{d\phi} \left( \frac{1}{u} \right) = -\frac{l}{\mu} \frac{du}{d\phi}.
$$

I am having a great deal of trouble figuring out how to get to that last equality. In general, $u$ is a function of $\phi$, so we can't just bring $u$ through the derivative. And where does that negative sign come from? I have been banging my head against this for a while, so I very much appreciate any insight.

Comment: You just need to apply the chain rule.

Comment: since this a common textbook derivation, have you looked at other textbooks?

Comment: I have — Baierlein and Goldstein— but I can’t find the relevant detail. I certainly understand that the previous step comes from the chain rule, but I don’t see how the third step does

Comment: @Bunji Using the chain rule on $d(u^{-1})/d\phi$ gives $-u^{-2}du/d\phi$

Comment: Oh! I see. Thank you so much!